# Регулярные выражения. Номер телефона с кодом города и номер ICQ

Tags: icq, регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки.
У меня к Вам следующий вопрос.
Есть две задачи, связанные с регулярными выражениями.

1. Создать паттерн для номера icq. Фишка в том, что в строке должны присутствовать и дефисы и цифры, но дефисы не должны повторяться подряд и не должны стоять перед и в конце строки. Т.е. не должно быть такой картины (-485--21-12-).
2. Тут все посложнее. Очень важно чтобы телефон был с кодом страны и города. Т.е. в таком виде +7 (495) 33-222-11

Сложность в том, что номер телефона может быть 5 символов, а может быть и длиннее.

С телефоном я дошел вот до такого варианта:

```
$pattern = "/^\+(7)\s?\(([0-9]{2,7})\)\s([0-9\-]{1,15})$/";
```

Но он пропускает двойные дефисы и дефисы перед номером
Пример:

```
+7 (38542) -33--085-222-
```

Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь поможет.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097450/regex-for-icq-uin][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097450/regex-for-icq-uin

Comment: Спасибо, но повторюсь, проблема в том, что он пропускает подобные номера -123-45---67-

Answer (score 2):

Для номера наверное так:

```
^((\+?7|8)[ \-] ?)?((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}))?([ \-])?(\d{3}[\- ]?\d{2}[\- ]?\d{2})$
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, какие номера он должен пропускать? Попробовал на этом +7 (3854) 333-333-22 не сработало. =(
В патерне у вас есть пробелы. Скажите, их так и оставить или заменить на \s? заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Он пропускает номера вида +7 (495) 123-45-67, а номер, который привели Вы не может существовать в России, так как не соответствует Российскому плану нумерации. Насчет пробелов не знаю, так как не программирую на PHP, но на всякий случай я бы их заменил.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярка

```
ICQ: ([1-9])+(?:-?\d){4,}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема в том, что он пропускает подобные номера -123-45---67-